# Using IIS6, how can I place files in a sub-folder but have them served as if they were in the root?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, url-rewriting

Our ASP.NET 3.5 website running on IIS 6 has two teams that are adding content:

- Development team adding code.
- Business team adding simple web pages.

For sanity and organization, we would like for the business team to add their web pages to a sub-folder in the project:

> Root: for pages of development team
>
> Content: for pages of business team

**But**

We would like for users to be able to navigate to the business team content without having to append "Content" in their URLs, as described below:

> **Root**: Default.aspx  (*Available at: www.oursite.com/default.aspx*)
>
> **Content**: Popcorn.aspx  (*Available at: www.oursite.com/popcorn.aspx*)

Is there a way we can accomplish for making a config entry in an ISAPI rewrite tool for every one of these pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any way to test this right now, but I think you can use the -f flag on RewriteCond to check if a file exists, in either directory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -!f
RewriteCond Content/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.*) Content/(.*)
```

Something like that might do what you're after, too.

Answer (score 2):

Since the extensions will be ASPX, ASP.NET will pick up the request... you can write an HttpModule that checks for pages that yield a 404 and then check the subfolder also.

If you know that all pages with a certain format will be coming from that folder, then you can just rewrite the URL in ASP.NET (either in Global.asax or an HttpModule).